# chrome.PageCapture.saveAsMHTML not including script tags

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, but when I use saveAsMHTML method to capture a page that has  tags the resulting MHTML file doens't include those tags.

For example:

This is the original HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="./sample.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="vsc-initialized">
      Test:
      <button onclick="myFunction1()">sample_js</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

and when I open the resulting MHTML file on Chrome that's what I got:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
      Test:
      <button onclick="myFunction1()">sample_js</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is that right? The MHTML format should not contains  tags, is that why?

I've tried to find any info that could help me to understand exactly why this happens, but even loking at the MTHML's RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2557
) I haven't found anything.

Any clue will be welcome.

Kind regards,

Comment: Chrome's [own Save-as-MHTML feature](https://www.techgainer.com/enable-single-file-mhtml-support-chrome/) itself never saved scripts, which is intended, see https://crbug.com/669325

Comment: ah I see, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanx